# Get social media image from Github repository

Tags: javascript, cors, jekyll

I am currently trying to build a Jekyll site with github-pages, and I would like to gather [opengraph](https://ogp.me/) headers for each repository I own to create 'rich previews' of each repository.

I am able to add a 'Social Preview' image to Github, but this doesn't seem to be [exposed to the API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/). I also tried creating an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) but I get:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://github.com/user/repo. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

Finally I do wonder if my plugin [github-metadata](https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata/) already has the image, but I don't know how to read the generated data

Does anyone know if there is a way **which would be feasible in a github-pages environment** by which I could get this information into my site?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all exposed metadatas [here](https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata/blob/master/docs/site.github.md#available-repository-metadata).

There is no specific image that can be set for each repository. The only image available is owner's avatar : `{{ site.github.owner_gravatar_url }}`.

And you can generate you opengraph headers with help of [jekyll-seo-tag](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag) at build time. No more need to use javascript magic ;-)

Comment: David, sorry for the previous comment, whilst this is old I wanted to query again about the suggestion at the bottom, by 'generate opengraph headers' do you mean that I can get graphQL information about each repo at site.data.projects? From what I see of SEO tag it looks like I exposing data about my site only